# Django cannot embed a Youtube url in a frame

Tags: django, iframe, django-views, x-frame-options

I am trying to embed a youtube URL into a frame in a Django template. Each time I receive the same message in the console:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I have tried inserting two decorators before the view:

```
@frame_deny_exempt
@xframe_options_exempt
```

No effect. In a final test I inserted this statement into settings.py just to see if it would turn off the xframe check:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOWALL'
```

The same error appears.

I also tried removing the XFrameOptions middleware, no change.

This is in a local testing environment so I am using the Django web server, my production server (which I have not tried moving this to for obvious reasons) is an Azure instance running NGINX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an embeddable URL?

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780

It is YouTube that is providing the `X-Frame-Options` header that the browser is complaining about, which implies you are trying to embed the normal URL to the video.